# Application crashes when ComboBox1 of 2 changes value - ComboBox1 change event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a VBA NewBe (this is my first post asking a question on any VBA help site)  working on a Property/Expense Management application in excel. the ComboBoxes in question are used to select worksheets based on a Property ID, `propID`, in `cmbPropID` based on a range in a "Control" worksheet and the worksheet year, `wsYr`, in cmbYear determined by the individual propID's beginning year, `wsStartYr`, and the current calendar year, `wdCurYear`. I am able to select/activate and view all worksheets of the first property I select. However, when I select another property to work on the application crashes with `Debug error: 9 - Script out of range`! I have been going blind for over a week searching for a solution without success.

This issue is important in the overall functionality of the application. I hope someone is able to help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Below are the code sections for the ComboBoxes
The first configures `cmbPropID`
'this is an excert form MultiPage1
Case 2

```
    'configure cmbPropID  DDL
    wkstControl.Activate
    selectedRow = cmbPropID.ListIndex + 3   'I presume this is 3 instead of 2 because when using 2
                                                        'this throws an error - not sure why
    For Each cPart In wsCntrl.Range(Range("propIDs"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
     pAct = wsCntrl.Cells(selectedRow, 11).Value 'Value used to test the "isActive" status of a  RealEstate property location
      With Me.cmbPropID
        If pAct = True And cPart.Value <> "" Then cmbPropID.AddItem cPart.Value 'Never Shows pAct as False ???
            'this presents an issue that if  is inActive of does'nt have worksheets it causes
            ' Debug error "Error: 13,  Type Mismatch"
      End With
    Next cPart
```

This sub configures the contents of the `cmbYears` DDL and should reset the DDL's contents when selection a different `propID` ... see notes in next sub-routine

```
    Private Sub cmbPropID_Change()
    Dim i
    Dim strValue As String
    wsCntrl.Activate
    pID = ""
    wsA = ""
    wsYr = "" 
    selectedRow = cmbPropID.ListIndex + 2
    
    wsStartYr = wsCntrl.Cells(selectedRow, 13).Text
    
          With cmbYears
                .Clear
    
            For i = wsStartYr To wbCurYear
                pAct = wsCntrl.Cells(selectedRow, 11).Value
                If wbCurYear <> wsStartYr And pAct = True Then
                    .AddItem i
                ElseIf wbCurYear = wsStartYr Then
                    .AddItem wbCurYear
                End If
            Next i
          End With
    lstDsplyUtil1.RowSource = ""
    pID = cmbPropID.Text
    
    End Sub
```

and finally, cmbYears. The code crashes at `Set wsUtil = Worksheets(wsA)` when a when `cmbPropID` changes.

```
    Private Sub cmbYears_Change()
     wsYr = cmbYears.Text
     wsA = pID & "_" & wsYr
        Debug.Print pID, wsYr, wsA
     Set wsUtil = Worksheets(wsA) 
     lstDsplyUtil1.RowSource = wsA & "!$A$5:$Y$16"
     
    Debug.Print pID, wsYr, wsA
    'Remove after testing
    Label120.Caption = wsA
    Label136.Caption = pID
    Label138.Caption = wsYr
    Label134.Caption = lstDsplyUtil1.RowSource
    
     wsUtil.Activate
     
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to troubleshooting the `Crash Issue` after posting my `Question`. I developed the habit of creating `Labels` on the various `UserForms`, assigned their `.Caption` value equal to the the various `Variable` values, and used `Debug.Print` to track those `Values` in the `Immediate Window`.

What I noticed was that when `Debug` threw its `Error` the `Immediate Window` showed the new `pID Value` `after` the `cmbPropID_Change() Event` to be the same as `BEFORE` the `cmbPropID_Change Event` and the `cmbPropID.ListIndex = -1` when it should have been `>=0` depending on the selection in `cmbPropID`. This lead me think that the problem was with the `cmbPropID_Change() Event configuration`. However, no matter what changes I made to the `cmbPropID_Change() Event configuration` the issue remained.

I began looking at the `cmbYears_Change() Event configuration` where the `Error` happens and it occurred to me that I could `pre-Trap` and thereby avoid the `Error` by encapsulating `cmbYears_Change() code` in a set of `If Then ElseIf` statements like this:

```
    If cmbYears.ListIndex <> -1 Then
      'cmbYears' original code
      ElseIf cmbYears.ListIndex >= 0 Then
      'cmbYears' original code
    End If
```

This worked perfectly and this is the final code!

```
    Private Sub cmbYears_Change()

    If cmbYears.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        pID = cmbPropID.Text
        wsYr = cmbYears.Text
        wsA = pID & "_" & wsYr
        lstDsplyUtil1.RowSource = wsA & "!$A$5:$Y$16"
    Debug.Print pID, wsYr, wsA
    Set wsUtil = Worksheets(wsA)
    wsUtil.Select
  ElseIf cmbYears.ListIndex >= 0 Then
    pID = cmbPropID.Text
    wsYr = cmbYears.Text
    wsA = pID & "_" & wsYr
    lstDsplyUtil1.RowSource = wsA & "!$A$5:$Y$16"
    Debug.Print pID, wsYr, wsA
    Set wsUtil = Worksheets(wsA)
    wsUtil.Select
End If

End Sub
```

Issue Resolved!