# Non-Standard "Conditional" configuration of ComBox1

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

My problem is how to populate the `cmbSelProp ComboBox` with `propIDs` from a workbook scoped Named Range called `PropLocs`. The columns of interest Column "A" which contains the list of `propIDs` and Column "K" which contains the `ActiveStatus` of each `propID`. I also have Named Ranges  for both columns of interest, `propIDs` and `actStatus` respectively. The `actStatus`, Column "K", portion of the range are set to True/False when the properties are added and subsequently initialized and annual worksheets are automatically generated.
I only want `cmbRptPrpID` populated with `propIDs` having an `actStatus = True`.

I have spent many hours over the past few weeks going blind doing Web Searches, looking at links, and trying suggestions from the various links without success. I,m as "Lost as a blind man in a snow storm!"

There are broader issues associated with the problem I am dealing with and understanding how to solve, and understand, the issue at hand will help me in the future development of my application.

**UPDATE**

[image]

the 2 mentioned additional ranges are in columns "A" and "K"

**Update 2**

***Business Logic***
The application I am developing utilizes a `multipage` object and there are pairs of `dynamic comboboxes`, `cmbSelProp` and `cmbYears` for example, used to select the `active worksheet` and enter Monthly expenses, view/generate Reports, etc. `cbmSelProp`selects the property ID, and the `cbmSplProp_Change() event` configures `cmbYears list values` based on the variable `wsStartYr` in column "K" and `wbCurYear` which is the Current Calendar Year. the annual worksheets have a Worksheet `TabName` of `propId_Year` and are selected using a variable `wsA = pID & "_" & wsYr`. I ***do not*** want `propIDs` with an `Inactive status` to appear as a part of the `cmbSelProp` list values.

This is a link to [My First Question here on StakOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72052615/application-crashes-when-combobox1-of-2-changes-value-combobox1-change-event) which is related to this question.

I really need some help figuring this out!
Thanks in advance for your assistance.
here is the code I have been trying to work with.

```
        selectedRow = cmbSelProp.ListIndex + 3
        
        For Each cPart In wsCntrl.Range(Range("propIDs"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         pAct = wsCntrl.Cells(selectedRow, "K").Value
          With Me.cmbSelProp
            If pAct = "True" And cPart.Value <> "" Then cmbSelProp.AddItem cPart.Value
          End With
        Next cPart
```

Comment: No use of named range "PropLocs" in your code?

Comment: @Tim Williams, initially I tried to use the `PropLocs` range in the code but it populated the List with the values of every cell in the range. This is why I set up the "propIDs' and `actStatu` ranges that appear in the code. Sometimes it's difficult to provide COMPLETE clarity.   Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What's the connection between `cmbRptPrpID` and `cmbSelProp` ?  A screenshot of your data would be useful here.

Comment: Description and and `Code Snippet` updated. I'm not sure how `cmbRptPrpID` got in there. that `ComboBox` uses the same code for configuration as does several other `ComboBoxes` in the project. I'm very new to VB - began self learning almost 2 months ago.

Comment: OK I'm still not following the logic sequence here - your code only reads one value from ColK, based on the selected list index and then - if the ColK value is True - loops over the table and adds all non-blank ColA values to the same list? Not sure why you'd do that. It would be helpful to explicitly describe the business logic for populating the list.

Comment: that is the crux of the problem. I have not been able to read `Columns "A" and "K"` of each row in the range,, determine if Column "K" in each row is `True` and populate the `List` ONLY with the values from `Column "A"` when `Column "K"` on that row has a value of `True".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code.  Rather than breaking down all the errors/issues, I'll show you how I would do it.

From your previous Q, I take it that your Combo Box is on a Userform.

I've created a Userform with a combo box and a button to load it.  You can change how you call the load function to suit your needs.

The UserForm code

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnTest_Click()
    Load_cmbSelProp
End Sub

Private Sub Load_cmbSelProp()
    Dim propIDs As Range
    Dim actStatus As Range
    Dim rw As Long

    Set propIDs = ThisWorkbook.Names("propIDs").RefersToRange
    Set actStatus = ThisWorkbook.Names("actStatus").RefersToRange
    Me.cmbSelProp.Clear
    For rw = 1 To propIDs.Count
        If propIDs.Cells(rw, 1).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            If actStatus.Cells(rw, 1).Value2 = True Then
                Me.cmbSelProp.AddItem propIDs.Cells(rw, 1).Value2
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The Named ranges
[image]

The result
[image]

Comment: Chris, I only had to glance at your code to know why I was `chasing my tail` trying to solve my issue. Your answer not only solved my immediate issue, it gave me insight into how to address a dozen other potential issues during my `app` development . I do have one question about this line of code for future reference: `propIDs.Cells(rw, 1).Value2 `. What is the significance of ` .Value2 `?  I've always seen this expressed as `.Value `  and during my testing using either `.value` or `.value2` return the same results.

Comment: @hermannjt [have a read of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)

Comment: your link and the link on that page provided a great deal of insight into programming structure. I'll do an experiment with one of my Annual Worksheets which has 20+ cells to update using the `Text` format . I notices that it takes several seconds to show the update. Thanks again for the assistance.